# In Ruby when you initialize a class do you set an instance variable equal to a variable?

Tags: ruby, class, variables

Why in ruby, when you initiazlize a class do you set the instance variable equal to a variable of the same name?

```
def initialize(number)
    @number = number
end
```

Comment: It is simpler. Why would you want to assign different names?

Comment: regarding close-votes: what's unclear in this question? IMHO, a bit strange (like asking why do you call a dog Jack) and somewhat opinion-based, but perfectly clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do that so that newly-created object (not a class! with initialize and @vars, you initialize the object that was just created with `new()` method!) remembers the value of `number`.

Try using this one:

```
def initialize(number)
end
```

This gets a number, but does nothing with it. When this inializer ends, the object created will not remember what was the 'number'.

Here:

```
def initialize(number)
  @foo = 5
  @bar = number
end
```

the newly-created object will remember a 5 in @foo and the number in @bar.

The idea to name the @variable just like the parameter is just to make it easier. In the example above, it's hard to guess what the `bar` is about. Instead, if I rename the @bar into @number, it wil be obvious that it holds .. the number.

```
def initialize(number)                         def initialize(number)
  @bar = number          <-same thing->          @number = number
end                    just different name     end
```

Comment: Maybe it would be more obvious to change the argument name and not the instance variable.

Comment: @Stefan: Possible.. I was focused on the question though, and wanted to show that the instance-var-name does not need to be the same.